# Code/Latex blocks in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: php, latex, yii, wysiwyg, codeblocks

Are there any open source libraries in PHP that implement code blocks and latex blocks in WYSIWYG text editor? I am building a PHP application using Yii framework and can find regular text editors but want to augment them with latex and code blocks. Any existing solutions for this yet?

Comment: does this help? https://fling.seas.upenn.edu/~subhrabh/cgi-bin/wiki/index.php?n=Projects.ITPmWiki-LaTeXinPmWiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [PhpMathPublisher](http://www.xm1math.net/phpmathpublisher/) or try to integrate [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) moving the LaTex rendering on the client side.